# Cannot see contraints in compose preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, preview

I'm learning Android Jetpack Compose and I'm currently experimenting with Constraint layout manager.
I'm working with Android Studio Iguana, I didn't try with previous versions so I won't linger.

The tutorial I'm following says that hovering over the preview causes annotation to appear indicating the constrains that have been applied to the components.

I could not see these annotation actually and strived to find out whether the annotations have to be enabled in menu item or in the compose preview. I couldn't.

There is something I'm missing.